# nginx ignores server_name and default_server

Tags: nginx, dns-hosting

I want to serve two domains from the same IP. This is my config:

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$server_name $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  mysite1.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        location / {
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
    server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name mysite2.com;
       root /var/www/mysite2.com;
       access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite2.com  main;
    }    
    server {
        listen       8443 ssl;
        listen       [::]:8443 ssl;
        server_name  mysite1.com;
        client_max_body_size 232m;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/all.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key ....
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location /static/ {
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            alias /usr/share/nginx/static/;
            add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
            open_file_cache_valid 1s;
        }        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9443;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can never get content of /var/www/mysite2.com/index.html. I always get content of mysite1. If I switch mysite2.com to port 81, then it delivers correct page on port 81, so this server block is functional. I tried setting default_site to mysite2, but it doesn't help, all the time I get content from mysite1. Also in logs I never see requests for mysite2, even if its being served (/var/log/nginx/mysite2.com is empty).

How can I fix this? Tried googling, reading other answers, nothing helped.

Comment: What is the purpose of the server block listening on port 8443, which just confuses your question as that is also mysite1?

Comment: 8443 is serving https://mysite1, 8443 is redirected to standard https port by router.

Comment: The configuration looks ok, so I would assume that there must be something different behind your issue. How do you test? Are you using a browser or cli tools like wget or curl? I would recommend to use wget or curl to avoid caching and browser internal HSTS (preferring https sites) behavior.

Comment: I tried both web browser and curl to second site, both of them return content of the first one.

Comment: Please add a default location block to the server block of your second site and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the problem. The problem was not in nginx settings themselves, rather in the fact that there was another server running (the one which was supposed to be tunneled). And that another server has taken http port, nginx **wouldn't warn you** that port is already taken, so it was not so easy to notice. May be this situation may somehow be a case for anyone.